# SSD drupal performance improvement

Tags: 7, performance

There are some VPS services that advertise that have SSD. Does it worth the extra money?

In a setup with varnish/nginx/php-fpm/apc/drupal/mysql, would SSD provide any significant performance improvement in drupal 7?

If yes, in which case scenarios?

Comment: In scenarios that use a lot of I/O.

Answer (score 2):

I am managing a site that gets about 1000 unique visitors a day. Not sure how big your application is, but 1000 is enough to cripple a default drupal install.

I added the standard performance optizations, apc, etc, but found that memcache by far had the best result. My pages used to take 20 seconds to load. Now pages load instantaneously. If you have not tried that, I would see if that helped first before investing in the SSDs.

Answer (score 0):

faster disk writing/loading.

E.g a site frequently getting user upload content such as photo album.

Cant say worth the penny as every project is different

Answer (score 0):

Only the provider is going to know if it makes an improvement.  They might get a performance benefit from a switching to SSD drives.  But what about providers that have very large hard drive arrays with standard 10,000 RAID drives?  There's much more involved to shard disk performance than what type of hard drive is being used in the arrays.

But it's important to know that Disk Drive performance is not nearly as important as the **software they provide and support, the CPUs and memory**.  The modules you listed above will provide users with a snappy Drupal site, but not all hosts support them so that is much more important.

[Tips on Choosing Suitable Drupal Hosting Providers](http://blog.wearepropeople.com/best-drupal-hosting-websites/)

Prices of SSD have gone down, and it makes good business sense to use them, but it's not going to be a big improvement in Drupal performance.

Varnish and APC however are wonderful ways of improving performance.

Answer (score 0):

SSDs are going to be great when you have a lot of file I/O.

Unless you have this occurring in your installs of Drupal, my advice is to stick with the proven technologies for improving performance & scalability for Drupal: APC, varnish, memcached, removing unused modules, etc.

The SSD may not be worth the extra money, not yet at least. If you are looking to fork over the extra money, get more CPUs, memory, disk, etc.